# Creating a new SolverManager for each user request to enable timeout configuration

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

We have modelled a VRP with Optaplanner. One requirement is that API users should have the ability to configure timeouts for the solver.

The documentations of both Optaplanner and Timefold [suggest using a config template and adjusting that during runtime to create a new SolverFactory for each request](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#solverConfigurationByJavaAPI). That currently would not be a problem. However, since we like the feature of `SolverManager` to provide continuous feedback to the user, I would like to know if there is an approach or "best practice" here to adjust the termination configuration of a `SolverManager`.

If we would create a new `SolverManager` from an adjusted `SolverConfig` for each request, wouldn't that kind of defy the some of the intentions of this class?

Side question: It seems timefold hasn't made any changes in that area (configuration per user request). Are there any changes planned here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the larger question first - there is no way to have a different termination for different jobs in the same `SolverManager` instance, created from a single `SolverConfig`. And you are right that this sort-of negates the benefits of `SolverManager` in this case; we simply didn't anticipate that people would do this.

That said, I think this is a completely valid feature request; one which we have [already discussed internally](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/150). We generally don't make commitments as to what feature will show up in Timefold Solver and when, but this feature would certainly be useful.